# Swift - Changing Annotation Image Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have followed other stack posts and tutorials in changing my annotations image to a custom one, but it does not seem to work. No errors or runtime errors appear, it's just that the annotation image does not change.

Just by the way  I set a break point on the line `annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "RaceCarMan2png.png")` and it shows that the line is being called, but yet nothing happens. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let identifier = "MyCustomAnnotation"

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "RaceCarMan2png.png")

    } else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }


    configureDetailView(annotationView!)

    return annotationView
}

func configureDetailView(annotationView: MKAnnotationView) {
        annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "url.jpg"))
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `MKPinAnnotationView`. If you use `MKAnnotationView`, you will see your image.

In the past (e.g. iOS 8), setting the `image` of `MKPinAnnotationView` seemed to work fine, but in iOS 9 and later, it uses a pin, regardless (which is not entirely unreasonable behavior for a class called `MKPinAnnotationView`; lol).

Using `MKAnnotationView` avoids this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Call that before return

```
if let annotationView = annotationView {
    // Configure your annotation view here
    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "RaceCarMan2png.png")
}

return annotationView
```

and check with breakpoint if it is ok inside `if`